# HTML5: video readystate === 4, still video is hanging during playing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, html5-video

I am working with html5 **`video`** and **`audio`**.

I play video after it's **`readyState === 4`** but still sometime **`video`** is hanging. I don't know why it's happen.

I want that if **video's** **`readyState === 4`** then video must be play smoothly.

Comment: Use a `canplay` Event instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I play video after it's readyState === 4 but still sonetime video is hanging.

`readyState` of `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA` (`4`) doesn't mean that a buffer under-run can't happen.  It just means that the browser currently *predicts* that it won't.  This predication is based on the average bitrate of the stream, the recent speed at which data has been downloaded, and the current state of the playback buffer.

If network conditions change, this prediction is no longer valid.  For example, a browser cannot predict that you walk around a building and lose your cellular or WiFi coverage and cannot keep streaming.  It's also the case that the internet is a pretty hostile network condition... things go wrong all the time, loads change, therefore available bandwidth is always in flux.

There really isn't anything you can do about this, other than be more aggressive about picking lower bitrate video if that `readyState` changes.